# What is the behaviour of a join on columns not in both tables?

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, left-join

```
table: users
columns: id

table: products
columns: id

table: product_images
columns: product_id |  path

table: cart
columns: user_id | product_id
```

product_id in the bottom 2 tables corresponds to id in the products table.
user_id in the cart table corresponds to id in the users table.

My friend and I are developing a generic shopping website just for fun.

The requirement: Given a user_id, go through the user's shopping cart and return all corresponding rows in the products table and with exactly 1 image for the product (there may be multiple images).

This is our query (which seems to work):

```
SELECT products.*, product_images.path
FROM products
INNER JOIN cart 
ON cart.product_id = products.id AND cart.user_id = 13  /* arbitrary id */
LEFT OUTER JOIN product_images 
ON product_images.product_id = cart.product_id
GROUP BY cart.product_id
```

The first join is intuitive to me because both tables involved in the join are joining on columns within each table.

It is the 2nd join that I am confused about.
My understanding is that the first join will produce a virtual table.
This virtual table is then joined with the product_images table, but the confusing part is that the ON condition is not using a column belonging directly to the virtual table.

So what exactly is going on here?

Please note that I know how to rewrite the query in a way that is more intuitive to me, and that it is understanding the concept that is important to me.

At first I thought this was uncommon, but I noticed w3schools does the same thing at the bottom of this link: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: Is it you want all products that have exactly 1 image and that are in carts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cart` and `products` are inner joined.

The virtual table going on to the next join **includes all columns from `cart` and all columns from `products`**.

This virtual/logical table will be as below.

```
SELECT products.id,
       cart.user_id,
       cart.product_id
FROM   products
       INNER JOIN cart
         ON cart.product_id = products.id
            AND cart.user_id = 13;
```

So there are three columns in this virtual table. `products.id`,`cart.user_id`,`cart.product_id`

This virtual table is then left joined onto `product_images` using a column from `product_images` and `cart.product_id` from the virtual table.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  I've been reading and rereading what you've said while trying out different (but similar) queries.  
I don't understand what you mean by "This is then left joined onto product_images using a column from product_images and a column from cart."  My understanding is that the right table involved in this left join will consist of all columns and rows of the product_images table minus any rows that do not have a corresponding product_id in the cart table.  
Assuming that's true, I still don't understand how the virtual table is joined w this new product_images table.

Comment: @KacyRaye - The left table involved in that join is `products * carts` so that brings into scope all columns from products and carts. The right table involved is `product_images` so that brings into scope columns from `product_images`. So the left join predicate can reference columns from any of those three tables.

Comment: @KacyRaye And your question says "the confusing part is that the ON condition is not using a column belonging directly to the virtual table." So rows aren't relevant here at all. If you are confused about the result in general see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins/27458534#27458534). The explanation for left outer join is exactly the same it is just that the table on the left is not a base table but is the result of the query in my answer.

Comment: I went through all the examples you provide and they all make perfect sense, but I feel like this is a separate case.
Oh, I think it may have just clicked. Can you confirm?
The ON condition for the left join is actually using the product_id column in the virtual table and not some separate instance of the original cart table?

Comment: @KacyRaye - Yes it's using the product_id column from the virtual table (which of course is derived from `cart` originally).

Comment: Wow, that was the little detail I was missing.  Thank you!

Comment: @KacyRaye - I think my answer could have been clearer on that point. Hopefully it is now!

Comment: Hey Martin, can I ask you something kind of related? Is the Group By using cart.product_id in the virtual table? 

Also, is the Group By being applied immediately after the last join, or is it applied after the Select completes?

Comment: @KacyRaye - **Logically** the `GROUP BY` happens after the joins and where clause if present. So it would be using the `cart.product_id` column in the virtual table resulting from the second join. The `SELECT` logically runs almost last. The only step that happens after that is `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.